# iOS 7 retrieve Inbox directory from documents

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like create a path to **Inbox** directory situated in **Documents** directory to read the file list.

The problem is that when I try to create the path, this isn't like the one I receive when use "Open in..." functionality.

Here the url from `application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method

*/private/var/mobile/Applications/555DB980-71E2-4AC5-8B12-34F1BBDE975B/Documents/Inbox/myFile.xlsx*

and here the path created with this code:

```
#define DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0]
#define INBOX_DIRECTORY     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY, @"Inbox"]

NSLog(@"%@",INBOX_DIRECTORY);
```

*/var/mobile/Applications/555DB980-71E2-4AC5-8B12-34F1BBDE975B/Documents/Inbox*

Why the start */private* folder is missing ? How can I get the correct path ?

### Solution based on @Mateusz Szlosek answer

It's the same path even if one starts with `/var` and the other one starts with `/private/var`

Comment: Don't use the format with `/` but use [`stringByAppendingPathComponent :`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_). `#define INBOX_DIRECTORY [DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on OS X `var` is a link to `private/var` maybe it's the same on iOS 7?

> lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root       wheel       11  9 lis 15:17 tmp -> private/tmp

Comment: Yes, work even if the path starts with `/var` instead with `/private/var`

Comment: So how do I expand the `/var/mobile/...` url to follow the link and show `/private/var/mobile/...`?